How to type the multiplication symbol (×) on a standard keyboard?
On a standard German keyboard it is: Shift + Alt Gr + Comma
Alt Gr is the right Alt key. Does it work the same way on English and other keyboards?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111624

Shift + AltGr+, produces × (the math times symbol) on the English (UK) keyboard.
I would not expect any different behaviour with other English (XX) derived keyboards

Difference: Shift + AltGr+* produces × on a Swedish keyboard.

@Hannu thanks for the edit
